# .each to return value in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Let say I have 4 div elements:

```
<div class="example"></div> //empty
<div class="example"></div> //empty
<div class="example">hi</div> //has content
<div class="example"></div> //empty
```

Then using `.each`, I want to assign value of either 0 (empty) or 1 (has content):

```
var container = {}; 

container['status'] = $('div.example').each(function(){                 
         var inside = $(this).html();

         //Check for empty
         if (typeof inside == 'undefined' || inside == '' || inside == '<br>') {                        
             var warning = 0;

         }else{
             var warning = 1;

         }  
         return warning;

       });  

console.log(container);
```

In this scenario, I want to get "0,0,1,0" as the returned value. How would I do this?

Comment: Use map instead of each().  each does not return

Comment: Ah i see. Thanks! I will give it a try!

Comment: I think we need more answers, lol

Comment: lol. haha, More the merrier :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function instead - see demo below:

```js
var container = {};

container['status'] = $('div.example').map(function() {
  var inside = $(this).html();
  //Check for empty
  if (typeof inside == 'undefined' || inside == '' || inside == '<br>') {
    var warning = 0;
  } else {
    var warning = 1;
  }
  return warning;
}).get();

console.log(container);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example">hi</div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.map()` to return an array of value

```
var container = {}; 

container["status"] = $.map($('div.example'), function(el) {  
                        return !el.textContent.trim().length || $(el).is(":empty") 
                               ? 0 : 1
                      });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
container['status'] = $(selector).each(YourFunc)
```

Use `map` instead of each, then call `join` to join elements

```
container['status'] = $(selector).map(YourFunc).get().join()
```

Works in Jquery 1.10.2